# What is the gradient of a gradient?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields

I'm a student, trying to re-derive a result found in a paper by calculating the following in spherical coordinates:

$$\mathbf{I}+ \frac{\nabla\nabla}{\mathrm{constant}},$$

where $\mathbf{I}$ is a $3\times 3$ identity matrix.

The paper that I've seen writes the result as

\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\ 
\cos(\Theta)\cos(\Phi) & \cos(\Theta)\sin(\Phi) & -\sin(\Theta)\\ 
-\sin(\Phi) & \cos(\Theta) & 0
\end{bmatrix}

How do they get that? What is the gradient of a gradient in spherical coordinates? Is it a Hessian?

Please see equations 11 and 13 of the following paper:
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.369.921&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 1):

It's the [Vector Laplacian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Laplacian), which is kind of like a Hessian. You can find a spherical coordinate version of it [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorLaplacian.html).

Answer (score 1):

The $\nabla \nabla$ here is not a Laplacian (divergence of gradient of one or several scalars) or a Hessian (second derivatives of a scalar), it is the gradient of the divergence. That is why it has matrix form: it takes a vector and outputs a vector. (Taking the divergence of a vector gives a scalar, another gradient yields a vector again).