# Does the gradient of a gradient exist?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Does the gradient of a gradient exist and if yes, what is it and does it have a intuitive representation ?
Thanks for any answers!

Comment: What's this got to do with vectors? Are you asking about how the slope of a curve changes?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "vector differential operator"?

Comment: I'm referring to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient?wprov=sfla1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the gradient of a gradient?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1153878/what-is-the-gradient-of-a-gradient)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition, the "nabla", $\nabla$, can be used as the "divergence" or the "curl" both of which apply to vectors.  With $\vec{f}= f_x\vec{i}+ f_y\vec{j}+ f_z\vec{k}$,  $div \vec{f}= \nabla \cdot \vec{x}(x, y, z)= \frac{\partial f_x}{\partial x}+ \frac{\partial f_y}{\partial y}+ \frac{\partial f_z}{\partial z}$ and $curl \vec{f}= \nabla\times \vec{f}= \left(\frac{\partial f_y}{\partial z}- \frac{\partial f_z}{\partial y}\right)\vec{i}+ \left(\frac{\partial f_z}{\partial x}- \frac{\partial f_x}{\partial z}\right)\vec{j}+ \left(\frac{\partial f_x}{\partial y}- \frac{\partial f_y}{\partial x}\right)\vec{k}$.

Because these can be applied to vector valued functions, we can apply either of them to the vector valued "grad f".  In particular, $\nabla\cdot \nabla f$ takes scalar valued f to a scalar valued function.  That is often symbolized as $\nabla^2 f$ or (more physics texts) $\triangle f.  As long as the function has differentiable partials so that the mixed derivatives are equal, "curl grad f" is the 0 vector so you never see that.

Answer (score 3):

Exactly what do you mean by "gradient"?  To those who speak "British English", the "gradient" of a function is just what those who speak "American English" would call the "derivative".  If that is what you mean then, yes, the "gradient of a gradient" is the "second derivative".  For example, if $f(x)= x^3$ then the gradient of f is the first derivative, $f'(x)= 3x^2$ and the "gradient of the gradient", or "second derivative" is the derivative of that: $f''(x)= 6x$.

But to those who speak "American English" and say "derivative" rather than "gradient", the gradient is a vector-valued operator.  The "gradient" is applied to a scalar valued function of several variables and results in a vector valued function.  Given a function of more than one variable, the gradient of that function is the vector, each of whose components is the derivative in that direction.  If $f(x, y, z)= x^2ye^z$ then the "gradient" of f is $\nabla f= 2xye^z\vec{i}+ x^2e^z\vec{j}+ x^2e^z\vec{k}$.  Since the "gradient", in this sense, must be applied to a scalar valued function and the result is a vector valued function, no you cannot apply the gradient a second time.  There is no "gradient of the gradient".

Comment: I'm referring to the vector differential operator, though I use British English. I just find the term "gradient" in the context of vector calculus to be more dominant. Thank you for the answer and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: This is wrong. The gradient is a specifically defined thing in mathematics and is subtly different from the derivative. We have directional derivative Df[x](v) which is something like "the best linear approximation to f at x in the direction v". If we can express Df[x](v) as an inner product (or dot-product) between a vector and v:

Df[x](v) = <g, v>

If there exists a unique vector g with this property, then g is called the gradient vector.
There are cases where the gradient vector does not exist but the directional derivative does. It all depends on your inner product

Answer (score 1):

The gradient of a gradient is commonly called the second derivative. A hill with a constant slope has a gradient, but the gradient of the gradient is zero. If the hill gets steeper as you get near the top then the  gradient of the gradient would be a positive number.

Comment: I'm referring to the vector differential operator, though I use British English. I just find the term "gradient" in the context of vector calculus to be more dominant. Thank you for the answer and sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

There is the array of gradients of each component of $\nabla f(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, that is called hessian matrix of $f$ (usually denoted by $\nabla^2 f$ in nonlinear optimization texts) or the jacobian of $\nabla f$. It is associated with the curvature of the function in each point.

Comment: I'm referring to the vector differential operator, though I use British English. I just find the term "gradient" in the context of vector calculus to be more dominant. Thank you for the answer and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You're welcome. I think "jacobian of the gradient" is what you meant to write, but since in some sense the gradient can be seen as simply the "jacobian of $f$ transposed", then abusing of the notation, $\nabla (\nabla f)=J(\nabla f)^t=\nabla ^2f$ is the "gradient of the gradient" you said, because $J(\nabla f)$ is symmetric. So what you wrote is not actually "wrong".