# Are all vector fields gradients of functions?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Just what the title says. I wanted to know if all vector fields are gradients of functions?

Comment: Are all vector fields conservative?  Are there vector fields with nonzero curl?

Comment: Look up the vortex vector field.

Comment: Isn’t $(-y,x)$ the most famous?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe what do you mean?

Comment: A simple example  of a vector field not being gradient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the function is one dimensional then yes. Take partial derivative of each variable to get the gradient.

If the function has higher dimensions with more than 1 variable then you obtain a matrix or tensor.

For example, take derivate of the gradient and you may obtain the Jacobian matrix which is not a vector.

Here is gradient of gradient [What is the gradient of a gradient?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1153878/what-is-the-gradient-of-a-gradient)

Answer (score 1):

No. Only *conservative* vector fields are vector fields that are the gradient of some function.

> **Definition**: A vector field **v**$ : U \to \mathbb{R}^n$, where $U$ is and open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, is said to be *conservative* if and only if there exists a $C^1$ scalar field $f$ on $U$ such that **v** $=$ $\nabla f$, where $\nabla f$ denotes the gradient of $f$.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner - Thank you for the grammar edit!